# How do I pull data from a Slack API response with WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net, slack-api, slack

I am making a portal for our team's Slack channel, and I'm wanting to pull a list of all of our current users using the Slack Web API - using the method `api/users.list`.

The code I am playing around with is:

```
var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/users.list",
                        "POST", new NameValueCollection()
                        {
                            { "token" ,"mySecretToken"}
                        });
```

I get an OK response back, but I'm having trouble actually finding out how to pull the data I want. When I look at the response object all I have is an array of bytes.

What am I missing to actually pull back an object with the user list information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to encode the response.

Just add this after:

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var responseText = encoding.GetString(response);
```

I can then use the responseText to pull out the data I need.